# Extract CMIP6 information with R

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I'm doing a research about climate change and I want to extract the CMIP6 information using R but I don't get the results I want. This is the code.

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
long_lat <- read.csv("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/Tesis/Coordenadas - copia.csv", header = T)
raster_pp <- raster::brick("pr_day_ACCESS-CM2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_2000.nc")
sp::coordinates(long_lat) <- ~XX+YY
raster::projection(long_lat) <- raster::projection(raster_pp)
points_long_lat <- raster::extract(raster_pp[[1]], long_lat, cellnumbers = T)[,1]
data_long_lat <- t(raster_pp[points_long_lat])
```

The cordinates I've used are the following: -77.7754,-9.5352 (latitude, longitude), but I've tried these as well and still doesn't work 102.2246,-9.5352. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Does `extract(raster_pp, cbind(XX, YY))` work for you?  Note that cmip data usually have longitudes measured from zero to 360 (not -180 to +180).

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get NA as a result, even when I've tried to change the coordinates.

Comment: Guessing these data are the down-scaled land product - so anything in the ocean mask will be NA. Make sure you're coordinates fall inside the land mask and that you have them in the correct order - i.e. X,Y is long,lat not the other way around

Comment: On another note, I would recommend updating your workflow to use the `terra` package instead of `raster`

Comment: So your coordinate is in Antarctica, close to the South Pole. Note that the lon 0..360 coordinate would be lat=-77.7754, lon=170.4648. Or are your coordinates reversed? (In which case this would be in a town in Peru.) If this is really what you want, maybe try for a location inside a temperate or subtropical or tropical location on a continent first.